# multivariate meta-analysis - can subgroup indicator reflect several different variables and outcome types?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, meta-regression, mixed-type-data, metafor

I have seen that in meta - analysis, a multivariate model can be used to get the same estimates as a series of separate meta analyses e.g.
https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:comp_two_independent_estimates

As I understand it, subgroup is incorporated as a categorical moderator in the model, as well as a random slope and appropriate correlation structure e.g. diagonal variance-covariance matrix to get the same estimates as a series of separate models on each subgroup.

If I understand correctly, this subgroup term is basically a variable to identify the outcome variable; the actual outcome variable to be modelled is an arbitrary numeric variable. If we are using standard meta analysis methods, that numeric variable will be a continuous variable assumed to be normally distributed.

In the linked tutorial, the subgroup appears to reflect a single moderator variable (namely "allocation"). However, I'm wondering whether its valid to collapse a series of variables to create this subgroup variable, for example disease type, disease stage and outcome type (e.g. proportions, odds ratios, risk ratios etc.). The numeric outcome variable and its variance to be modelled would need to be computed differently according to the type of outcome (proportion, ratio etc.). Then we can compute estimates all in one go, as opposed to running lots of separate models. We would have to be mindful that back transformations for later presentation, might differ according to the outcome type though.

I would be very grateful for some advice on whether this approach is valid.

Comment: Sure, that is possible and since the results would be identical to running separate analyses/models, it is a valid approach. Not sure what else to say about this, so I am leaving this as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Wolfgang. Rather than collapsing disease type, disease stage and outcome type into the subgroup variable (which is then included as a fixed effect and random slope) do you think it might be preferable to have these as separate fixed effects / interactions and corresponding random slopes? Or would that be overkill? Im not sure thats even possible (several random slopes) in metafor::rma.mv() but I think possible in e.g. lme4::lmer()?

Comment: I have now written up an answer that hopefully addresses your last question and the original question in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, that is possible and since the results would be identical to running separate analyses/models, it is a valid approach. Here is an example with two different effect size measures (log risk ratios and standardized mean differences), once combined in two separate models and once combined in the same model:

```
library(metafor)

dat <- dat.gibson2002

# to ensure that each study only provides information to compute one type of effect size
dat$m1i[!is.na(dat$ai)] <- NA

# compute log risk ratios and corresponding sampling variances
dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=ai, bi=bi, ci=ci, di=di, data=dat)
dat

# random-effects model to pool the log risk ratios
res1 <- rma(yi, vi, data=dat)

# compute standardized mean differences and corresponding sampling variances
dat <- escalc(measure="SMD", m1i=m1i, sd1i=sd1i, n1i=n1i, m2i=m2i, sd2i=sd2i, n2i=n2i, data=dat)
dat

# random-effects model to pool the standardized mean differences
res2 <- rma(yi, vi, data=dat)

# combine the results in a data frame
dat.comp <- data.frame(estimate = c(coef(res1), coef(res2)), stderror = c(res1$se, res2$se),
                       meta = c("LnRR","SMDs"), tau2 = c(res1$tau2, res2$tau2))
dfround(dat.comp, 3)

# compute both types of effect sizes
dat <- escalc(measure="SMD", m1i=m1i, sd1i=sd1i, n1i=n1i, m2i=m2i, sd2i=sd2i, n2i=n2i, data=dat, add.measure=TRUE)
dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=ai, bi=bi, ci=ci, di=di, data=dat, add.measure=TRUE, replace=FALSE)
dat$study <- 1:nrow(dat)
dat

# analogous model fitted with rma.mv() yielding the same results
rma.mv(yi, vi, mods = ~ 0 + measure, random = ~ measure | study, 
       struct="DIAG", data=dat, digits=3)
```

One can even take this further and do this for multiple variables that define various subgroups (based on their combination). Below is an illustration of this idea:

```
library(metafor)

dat <- dat.bcg

# calculate log risk ratios and corresponding sampling variances
dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat)

# create two dummy variables
dat$alloc <- ifelse(dat$alloc == "random", "random", "other")
dat$ablat <- ifelse(dat$ablat > 33, "far", "close")
dat

# all combinations of the two dummies are present
table(dat$alloc, dat$ablat)

# fit random-effects models within all subgroups created by the combination of the two dummies
res <- list(rma(yi, vi, data=dat, subset=alloc=="other"  & ablat == "close"),
            rma(yi, vi, data=dat, subset=alloc=="random" & ablat == "close"),
            rma(yi, vi, data=dat, subset=alloc=="other"  & ablat == "far"),
            rma(yi, vi, data=dat, subset=alloc=="random" & ablat == "far"))

# combine the results in a data frame
dat.comp <- data.frame(meta = c("random-far","random-close","other-far","other-close"),
                       estimate = sapply(res, coef), stderror = sapply(res, \(x) x$se),
                       tau2 = sapply(res, \(x) x$tau2))
dfround(dat.comp, 3)

# analogous model fitted with rma.mv() yielding the same results
rma.mv(yi, vi, mods = ~ 0 + alloc:ablat, random = ~ interaction(alloc,ablat) | trial, 
       struct="DIAG", data=dat, digits=3)
```

Comment: wow thanks so much @Wolfgang! I was literally just pondering more on an issue regarding number of effect estimates in group combinations which was related to this but I thought perhaps bordering on a new topic? I have posted the question here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/643739/meta-regression-as-mixed-model-time-interaction and would greatly appreciate your expert advice if you have time.

Comment: in your final rma.mv() function, is it correct that the 0 suppresses the intercept? I thought I read somewhere that this is not advised if we are modelling a continuous predictor i.e. ablat?

Comment: Also, I have seen in multivariate mixed models something like this for the fixed effects: alloc + alloc : ablat, though I must admit Im not clear why! May I please ask why you used only the interaction term in both the fixed effects and random slopes, and no main effects?

Comment: `ablat` is not continuous -- it was turned into a categorical variable. And `0 + alloc:ablat` will then give me the estimated pooled effect within each subgroup created by the combination of the two variables.

Comment: Oops sorry I overlooked that you recoded ablat to categorical. That seems unwise however; I was taught that categorising a continuous predictor is almost always a bad idea. Would it not be preferable to keep as continuous predictor? Then we can get "left hand side" conditional / marginal estimates of effect size for given ablat?

Comment: I was just using this as a toy example to illustrate that one can obtain the same results when subgrouping (also based on the combination of multiple variables) and when using an appropriate `rma.mv()` model. If you start adding continuous predictors, then we are dealing with a rather different case. But your question wasn't about this, so let's stick to what the question was about (i.e., subgroups, however defined).

Comment: Thanks @Wolfgang. I agree, thats moving to a new question. Indeed, the link to the other question I posted in the above comment contains the issue of a continuous predictor. Would be very grateful of your expertise on that one too!