# Meta regression as mixed model: time interaction

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, meta-analysis, meta-regression, metafor

In our meta-analysis, we have several potential moderators, both categorical (e.g. disease type, outcome type), and continuous e.g. publication year. Suppose we wish to investgate the effect of publication year on the effect size, within each disease x outcome combination. The number of publication year values varies across these group combinations, from 1 (gasp!) to 14. My thought was to attempt one big multivariate mixed model, where publication year is interacted with group combination, and random effects included for paper and row id (i.e. effect size within paper). Random slopes might also be considered. My concern is the low sample size in some group combinations e.g. how can we estimate the publication year trend in some groups, with such a small number of effect sizes? I am aware of advice such as 10 effect sizes per moderator etc. But Im wondering how such advice plays out here? I guess one option would be to only include in this meta regression model, the group combinations that have e.g. at least n=5 unique publication year values. Another option might be to use the full dataset (all group combinations) but only interact publication year in group combinations with e.g. n=5 unique publication year values. The final option I thought of is to fit the model on the full dataset (all subgroup combinations), and attempt to interact publication year with group combination regardless of whether some of these groups will have very low n to estimate the year slope. The groups with small n will borrow strength from other data points and therefore we can estimate the trend in all groups. The small n will be reflected in the wider confidence intervals for these groups. This is the kind of thing I have seen with mixed models, and since mixed models can be used to fit meta analytic models I dont see why we cannot apply the same methodology. I would greatly appreciate some advice!

Comment: Meta-regression is a form of mixed effects model so you can borrow insights from that field here. I would go for your final option but I have no source to back that up.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion @mdewey. I agree, the last option just kind of feels right!